# Marionette JST template rendering

Tags: templates, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to get Marionette render my JST templates, working in Rails environment. According to the tutorial and Marionette official documentation I have to override Marionette render methods:

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = (template, data) ->
path = JST["path/to/template/" + template]
unless path
    throw "error"
path(data)
```

And when calling template from the view:

```
    class myChildView extends Marionette.ItemView
      template: "specific-template-location/template"

    class myCompositeView extends Marionette.CompositeView
      template: "specific-template-location/template"
      childView: myChildView
```

I'm getting an `Uncaught error` upon rendering. Strangely enough, but when I've used `itemView` instead of a `childView` the templates were rendering properly. The tutorial I'm using already proved to be outdated, but I fail to find any correlation between differences of `childView` \ `itemView` and template declaration in the official documentation. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional information:** I also can't pass the template directly from the DOM (Marionette render override removed), i.e:

```
    class myCompositeView extends Marionette.CompositeView
      template: "#mytemplate"
```

Also throw a `no template error`. The only way I've managed to pass a template is through an Underscore template constructor - `_.template()`, which is at least indicates that there are no issues with passing a collection to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make like this:

```
do (Marionette) ->
  _.extend Marionette.Renderer,
  lookups: ['path/to/template/apps', 'path/to/template/components']

  render: (template, data) ->
    return unless template
    path = @getTemplate(template)
    throw "Template #{ template } not found!" unless path
    path(data)

  getTemplate: (template) ->
    for lookup in @lookups
      path = "#{ lookup }/#{ template }"
      return JST[path] if JST[path]
```

[I have one example here, using Rails too](https://github.com/SauloSilva/backbone-marionette-example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/config/marionette/renderer.js.coffee)

Comment: Oh, thanks a bunch. I've already solved it, but your approach is more configurable! If you don't mind, on a related note, how you get about using Rails helpers in your JST templates?